# is there a way to transform an numpy array or pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, arrays, image, tensor

I've been trying out some image recognition neural networks on an image dataset. My images are in the array (or tensor) of shape [39209, 30, 30, 3]. However, for some code I found on github my images are required to be of an array shape [39209, 3, 30, 30]. I assumed there would be a quick way to transform the array but it proved to be pretty difficult. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `torch.transpose` https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.transpose.html

```
import torch

a = torch.ones((10, 30, 30, 3))

b = torch.transpose(a, 1, -1)

print(b.shape)
```

`torch.Size([10, 3, 30, 30])`

`numpy` also has `transpose` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html

Comment: Welcome to SO, @JeroenVermunt. Don't hesitate to upvote/accept an answer if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `torch.permute()`:

```
x = torch.randn(1, 32, 32, 3).float()

x.shape
torch.Size([1, 32, 32, 3])

y = x.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)

y.shape
torch.Size([1, 3, 32, 32])
```

Comment: thanks, this is closer to np's transpose which is what I was looking for